# Como alterar uma tabela indicando que os dados de certo campo só podem variar da data 1 à data 2?

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle, data, pl-sql, timestamp

tenho uma tabela chamada "LOC_VEICULO" onde estão contidos os dados de veículos.
Nela possuo o seguinte campo: DT_FABRICACAO (DATE), onde estão armazenadas as datas de fabricações dos veículos.

Preciso alterar os veículos, indicado as datas de fabricação que devem variar de
02/01/2008 até 02/01/2010.

Como devo proceder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para impedir entradas de dados que não estão nessas datas você pode criar uma contraint na tabela, assim:

```
alter table LOC_VEICULO 
add constraint check_DT_FABRICACAO 
CHECK (DT_FABRICACAO between date'2008-01-02' and date'2010-01-02');
```

Ou criar uma trigger que te mostra o erro:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_valida_data
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE 
ON LOC_VEICULO
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    if (:new.DT_FABRICACAO not between date'2008-01-02' and date'2010-01-02') then
        raise_application_error(-20000,'O valor de Data de fabricação deve variar entre 02/01/2008 e 02/01/2010');
    end if;
END;
```

/